# Why does the address change after putting it in the GUI wallet's address book?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id, integrated-address, address

I used the GUI wallet's address book to store an address. When I added the address, the address was changed.

It went from 4Gdo... to 46w8M... the monero was sent and is confirmed on the blockchain, but no where to be found on the recipients wallet. Where did this monero go and is it even possible to recover it? There's over 15+ confirmations already.The Payment ID also ended up just being a bunch of 0's.

I searched around and saw that it might be because of a bug in the GUi wallet in trying to store an integrated address? I would appreciate the help!

Comment: If this is a bug report, it belongs to https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues rather than here. Please file a bug there, with all relevant details. Thanks.

Comment: The GUI beta 1 has unfortunately a Bug: when a Imntegrated address gets saved in Adressbook, in gets transformed to a normal address (without paymentid). However, the address stays the same. 

to better help you i need to know from where to where you sent money.

GUI to GUI, or GUI to exchnage ?

Comment: @medusa GUI to exchange. never showed up. and its not in my GUI balance anymore.

Comment: @moneronoobnomore since you sent to the exchange without paymentID, the exchange does not know it has to credit the monero to your account. Please contact the exchange and provide them with all the Info you have regarding that transaction: TransactionID, Transaction Key (visible in Transaction History, if you klick on Details), Amount and Time. Tell them you ran into a bug and please them to credit the monero to your accout. Please report back if there are issues or if they refuse to cooperate. For reference, this is the bug: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/392

Comment: Any further info on this question? could it be considered as resolved?

Comment: @medusa apologies for the delay in response, but thank you so much. the exchange credited my account after I contacted them with your advice. your help was and is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Integrated addresses are a standard address plus a short payment id packed into one (longer) address. Some software, including the GUI address book, but also Ledger, will unpack that integrated address and display the underlying standard address instead.

This annoying state of affairs should be a thing of the past once people switch to using subaddresses, which aren't made of two packed things.